# List of causes for LNK2038, MSVS2017 MAGMA

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, magma

### My goal is by compiling (pun not intended) a list of causes for LNK2038 "mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2'" that others may follow methodically to debug their own situations, my situation will be resolved

My situation:

**Requirements:**

- Windows 10
- CMake
- MSVS 2017
- Intel Paralax Studio XE
- CUDA

**To reproduce:**

1. Download [MAGMA](http://icl.utk.edu/projectsfiles/magma/downloads/magma-2.4.0.tar.gz)
2. Run CMake GUI

   - Manually set `GPU_TARGET=Pascal` (My Card: GeForce GTX 1070  Compute Capability: 6.1)
   - Manually set `MKLROOT=D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/parallel_studio_xe_2019.0.045/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl`   (as instructed in the README-Windows)
   - LAPACK_LIBRARIES: use https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor to determine

     - [My choice](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxcondyg70bj5md/Intel%20MKL%20libraries%20link%20int32.PNG?raw=1)
     - `D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/parallel_studio_xe_2019.0.045/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_intel_lp64.lib;D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/parallel_studio_xe_2019.0.045/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_intel_thread.lib;D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/parallel_studio_xe_2019.0.045/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_core.lib;D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/windows/compiler/lib/intel64_win/libiomp5md.lib`
3. From the generated VS solution, compile in *Debug mode* **magma** and **magma_sparse** projects (no need to compile the 600+ test projects)
4. In a separate folder put the [example code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h97dco364gdtow9/example_sparse.cpp?raw=1) and the [CMakeLists.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6n3rjnjr5ie3q9/CMakeLists.txt?raw=1)

   ```
   add_executable(magma-test example_sparse.cpp)

   find_package( CUDA ) # just to set CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS

   target_include_directories(magma-test PUBLIC D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/include D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/sparse/include ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   target_link_libraries(magma-test debug D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/build/lib/Debug/magma.lib debug D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/build/lib/Debug/magma_sparse.lib)

   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
   ```
5. Run CMake (Configure, Generate)
6. Open VS solution, and compile in *Debug mode*

**Problematic outcome:**

`1>magma_sparse.lib(magma_sparse_generated_djacobisetup.cu.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in magma.lib(interface.obj)`

`1>magma_sparse.lib(magma_sparse_generated_djacobisetup.cu.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in magma.lib(interface.obj)`

### ----------

### Things to check upon LNK2038:

1. All dependencies (*.lib files) were compiled with the same "Debug/Release" flags

   - Double check the dependencies actually being used by Right-click on your Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
   - Go to each dependency project and to your project, and check the build flags by Right-click on Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

Comment: For me, my example project "Additional Dependencies" lists D:\Work\Magma\magma-2.4.0\build\lib\Debug\magma.lib;D:\Work\Magma\magma-2.4.0\build\lib\Debug\magma_sparse.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib, 
and both my example code project, plus magma and magma_sparse project are "MTd" :(, what should I check next?

Comment: You are mixing Debug and Release. Everything must be Release or Debug no mixing is allowed unless the library was written in `c`.

Comment: I've deleted all the whole Release folder of MAGMA :( @drescherjm

Comment: and I've renamed magma.lib and magma_sparse.lib in the Debug folder to make sure they are the ones being used and , indeed it says "1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\Work\Magma\magma-2.4.0\build\lib\Debug\magma_sparse.lib'

Comment: After fixing the settings you probably have to do a clean build.

Comment: Did a "clean", and "rebuild" of MAGMA, and of my example project, three times already :/ @drescherjm

Comment: `target_link_libraries(magma-test debug D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/build/lib/Debug/magma.lib D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/build/lib/Debug/magma_sparse.lib)` there should be an entry for optimized if you want release.

Comment: I expect your problem is the libs in the Debug folder were not debug libraries. Not sure why.

Comment: Or perhaps the Debug libs have some Release dependency.

Comment: If magma_sparse.lib has a Release dependency, would it even compile in Debug mode? (bc it does compile; and I just deleted the MAGMA folder and did a complete rebuild from scratch *only* in Debug mode) @drescherjm

Comment: @WurmD any solution to this issue? I'm having the exact same issue :-(

Comment: @Vahid :( no, I gave up on MAGMA after I realized that their claim of "we'll determine where your code should run automatically (CPU or GPU)" was false for Sparse Matrixes (it's always in GPU). And they don't even standardize the code. The code to deal with sparse matrixes was different than the dense examples.

Answer (score 1):

A CMakeLists.txt that "resolves" the above error, compiles and runs is:

```
add_executable(magma-test example_sparse.cpp)

find_package( CUDA ) 
set( MKLROOT "D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/parallel_studio_xe_2019.0.045/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl" )
set( LAPACK_LIBRARIES 
   "D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/parallel_studio_xe_2019.0.045/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_intel_lp64.lib"
   "D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/parallel_studio_xe_2019.0.045/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_intel_thread.lib"
   "D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/parallel_studio_xe_2019.0.045/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_core.lib"
   "D:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/windows/compiler/lib/intel64_win/libiomp5md.lib")

target_include_directories(magma-test PUBLIC 
   "D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/include" 
   "D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/sparse/include" 
   ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   ${MKLROOT}/include)
target_link_libraries(magma-test 
   ${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY}
   ${CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES}
   ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY}
   ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}
   debug D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/build/lib/Debug/magma.lib 
   debug D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/build/lib/Debug/magma_sparse.lib
   optimized D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/build/lib/Release/magma.lib 
   optimized D:/Work/Magma/magma-2.4.0/build/lib/Release/magma_sparse.lib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
```

The CUDA and MKL libraries that MAGMA uses upon compilation seemingly also have to be provided for code that uses MAGMA libraries

**EDIT: Wait, no. It's compiling and running in Release, but not in Debug..**

Comment: I would have told you about using optimized in `target_link_libraries` but I thought you were building the Debug configuration.

Comment: Lol @drescherjm, txs.
What was missing was not that, was the target_include_directories(magma-test 
   ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   ${MKLROOT}/include), and the target_link_libraries(magma-test 
   ${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY}
   ${CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES}
   ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY}
   ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}